# Triage Review - Is it okay to specify only a problem without coding attempt as a good question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, triage

While reviewing, I just found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246983/sum-pattern-across-array) had only specific problem.

As mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) thought it is okay to ask for a programming problem, I just felt like stating the problem without making an attempt to solve it was not correct and flagged it as unsalvagable.

Kindly let me know, If there is anything I am missing/need to improve in reviewing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That question is asking how to accomplish a particular task with a certain tool.

*"How to"* questions are not always easy, and very often come across as being too broad, but apparently users in that tag appreciate that question. While many (maybe most) questions **need** code to work, there are cases of perfectly valid questions without any code in them.

I'm not an expert in that tag, but to me it seems that is quite narrow and specific; and as you can see by the existing answers, it doesn't need anyone writing an entire blog post or a complete tutorial to be be able to fully answer the question.

I believe the closing line in that question can also work as a red herring, making some users feel it is opinion based: *"What is the correct (general) way of doing this?"*. If you rephrased this so it's clear it is about "how to do this" (or simply removed it) I think it would be even clearer than the question is asking for specific instructions.

I imagine several different answers could be written, but that's not necessarily a sign that a question is too broad. We do want different, competing answers if possible, so that votes sort them out by perceived usefulness and quality.

All that being considered, I believe that you were wrong in choosing *Unsalvageable*, the question seems fine to me.

Finally, on the audit angle:

You got this question as an audit because audits are chosen automatically. The question had 5 upvotes and no down-votes, and that made it elegible as a "known good" question. Since then, "thanks" to the meta-effect, it got a couple of down-votes, so it will no longer be shown as an audit.

If you are not an expert in the tag of the post you are reviewing, and you are in doubt, remember there is no shame in clicking "skip" and leaving that review for someone else.

Comment: Thanks @yivi , As suggested may be I can skip the questions next time. Also your answer adds some value to how to review a question :)